what is "short range clearance procedure" like?
in my oral exam guid book
it says
"a traffic clearance issued prior to departure will normally authorize flight to　the airport of intended landing. Under certain conditions, at some locations, a short range clearance procedure is used, whereby a clearance is issued to a fix within or just outside of the terminal area, and pilots are advised of the frequency on which they will receive the long range clearance direct from the center controller"
what is the "Short-range clearance procedure"? and what is it like?

I don't know that this is common at all in the usa anymore, but the idea is that you would file a flight plan along the lines of
KABC..XXX.V10.YYY.J20.ZZZ..KDEF

and instead of being a full clearance all the way to "DEF airport" instead you would only be cleared so far as "YYY VOR." That is your clearance limit, and you would expect to receive further clearance before you reach the VOR. If you don't, you hold over the VOR and ask ATC for instructions.
Again, I don't know if that's common at all anymore. Current ATC procedures tell us to clear you all the way to your destination airport (even if it lies within uncontrolled airspace).
Something which might be a little more common is if you plan to fly VFR cross-country but a low layer of IMC prevents a VFR departure. You can request, or even file, IFR to a nearby fix—ideally this will be some fix right before but not all the way to the border of the TRACON or Center sector. ATC will clear you to that fix with the expectation that you'll cancel IFR once you break out on top. (This is sometimes referred to as an "on top" or "climb to on top" clearance, but it's not the same as a a true VFR-on-top clearance.)
